# Purge messages from specific member djs V13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

How would you purge messages from a certain user, with a limit to how many you can purge?
Needs to work with slash commands too

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking to purge messages of a specific channel or the whole server?

My first though would be to get the channel object and call awaitMessages function on it. It takes a parameter of a filter callback which accepts the message object. From that point on you can filter the message so its owner is matched with the selected user (lets say !purge 10 @user123). So every message would filter in a way that the owner must be @user123. After that you can call delete function upon acquired message objects.

I will show you a solution for purging user's messages in a specific channel.

Ref:

[DiscordJS - Documentation - TextChannel.awaitMessages](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages)

[DiscordJS - Documentation - Message.delete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Message)

```js
// Could throw an exception at channel.awaitMessages or 
// message.delete so make sure to handle it how you prefer.
async function purgeMemberMessages(
  channel, 
  memberId, 
  limit, 
  timeout = 60000
) {

  // Get all messages posted by the given user with a limit
  let messagesCollection = await channel.awaitMessages({
    filter: m => m.author.id === memberId,
    max: limit,
    time: timeout
  });
  
  // Convert the collection to an array
  let messages = Array.from(messagesCollection.values());
  
  // Delete each message
  for (let message of messages) {
    await message.delete();
  }
  
}

// we will assume you have access to the channel object
// let channel = ...
// userId will hold the value which user inputs through a slash command
let userId = '123456789';
// limit will hold the value which user inputs through a slash command as well
let limit = 100;
await purgeMemberMessages(channel, userId, limit);
```

Comment: It was through a certain channel, thank you.